# Is there a way to enable Caffeine MBean registration?

Tags: jmx, mbeans, caffeine, jmx-exporter, caffeine-cache

I am using Scaffeine in my project (https://github.com/blemale/scaffeine), a Scala wrapper for Caffeine (https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). I also have a prometheus JMX collector embedded in my metrics API (https://github.com/Segence/kamon-jmx-collector).

However when I launch my application, I can't really see any `MBeans` for Caffeine in VisualVM.

Also, when looking at the Caffeine project, I found that in the `caffeine/jcache/src/main/resources/reference.conf` there is a config for JMX monitoring:

```
monitoring {
      # If cache statistics should be recorded and externalized
      statistics = false

      # If the configuration should be externalized
      management = false
    }
```

Both are set to false. Is there a way to configure Caffeine so that it exposes MBeans to JMX?

Comment: You will want to register it - see their [docs](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#caches). Ignore the jcache module as a standard that is not recommended.

Comment: That was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Ben Manes,

This would be the answer according to prometheus:

```
import io.prometheus.client.cache.caffeine.CacheMetricsCollector

CacheMetricsCollector cacheMetrics = new CacheMetricsCollector().register();

Cache<String, String> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().recordStats().build();
cacheMetrics.addCache("myCacheLabel", cache);
```